# Cortex-M0+Determining stack frame size at run time

Tags: arm, stack, cortex-m, stack-frame

How can one determine the size of a stack frame for a function call at run time?

I could use CMSIS `__get_MSP` before and after the call and get the difference, but I would prefer to not require the caller to do anything before the call.

Knowing the frame sizes would allow deconstructing the stack which would be beneficial for analysing on a fault.

Comment: So, you want to use CMSIS functions?  With gcc, you can use [these frame built-ins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Return-Address.html) are they in scope of an answer or will you change the question because of some unexpressed requirement?  Ie, for 99% of functions, the compiler knows the answer and can supply it.

Comment: This depends on which compiler you use and how it is tuned.